# DBSCAN gives "AttributeError: NoneType has no attribute issparse"

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, python-2.7, clustering

I am running a Python script invoking the DBSCAN tool to cluster feature points.  When I open ArcMap, load the feature layer, and run the script, it works the way I expect it to.  But if I run it again with the same feature layer still open, I get:

```
AttributeError:  NoneType has no attribute issparse.
```

Here is a section of my code:

```
import sys, os
import arcpy

from math import sqrt
from math import atan2
from math import atan
from math import sin
from math import cos
from math import tan
from math import pi
from math import radians
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN

def llh2enu(lat_dd_orig, lon_dd_orig, ht_orig, lat_dd_pt2, lon_dd_pt2, ht_pt2):
...
# End function llh2enu definition
# Begin process
in_featureclass = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
in_scan_distance_str = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
in_scan_minpts_str = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)

eps = float(in_scan_distance_str)
min_samples = float(in_scan_minpts_str)

# Read data
X = []
cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(in_featureclass)
firstloop = 0

try:
    for row in cursor:
        lat_dd = row.getValue("Latitude")
        lon_dd = row.getValue("Longitude")
        # Set the origin for the enu coordinate sys as the first point
        if firstloop == 0:
            lat_orig = lat_dd
            lon_orig = lon_dd
            firstloop = 1
        e, n, u = llh2enu(lat_orig, lon_orig, 0.0, lat_dd, lon_dd, 0.0)
        X.append([e, n])
    del cursor
except arcpy.ExecuteError:
    arcpy.AddError("Failed reading values")
    sys.exit()
except:
    arcpy.AddError("Non-tool error occurred")
    sys.exit()

# Make X an array rather than a list.
X = np.array(X)

# Compute DBSCAN
db = DBSCAN(eps, min_samples).fit(X)
```

Here is where the error occurs.  Again, it runs just fine the first time the feature layer is open in ArcMap, but it gives me the `AttributeError` all subsequent times I run it.  I have to close ArcMap and reopen it with the feature layer to get it to work again.  I even put the following at the end just to be sure to free everything up:

```
del cursor
del X
del db
```

I put some diagnostic prints of the values of X in both scenarios, and the values of X are identical.

If I run the script more than once in ArcMap, whether I create the list and array X from a feature class or from a spreadsheet, I get the exception:

```
AttributeError: NoneType has no attribute issparse.
```

If I run the script outside ArcMap from the command line, and create the list and array X from a spreadsheet, I get no errors no matter how many times I run it.

Here is the traceback:

```
File "P:\Bailey\GaleK Tracks\test_dbscan.py", line 118, in <module>
    db = DBSCAN(eps, min_samples).fit(X)
File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cluster\dbscan_.py", line 248, in fit
    clust = dbscan(X, **self.get_params())
File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cluster\dbscan_.py", line 132, in dbscan
    X[index], eps, return_distance=False)[0]
File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neighbors\base.py", line 507, in radius_neighbors
    return_distance = return_distance)
File "binary_tree.pxi", line 1442, in sklearn.neighbors.dk_tree.BinaryTree.query_radius (sklearn\neighbors\kd_tree.c:11398)
File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 117, in array2d
    if sp.issparse(X):
AttributeError:  'NoneType' object has no attribute 'issparse'
```

As you can see, I am running Python 2.7 with ArcGIS 10.2.

---

As I mentioned before, the "AttributeError:  'NoneType' object has no attribute 'issparse'" error occurs the second and subsequent times I run the tool containing DBSCAN for a given feature layer.  For a clean exit, I put a "try" block around the DBSCAN call.

```
try:
    db = DBSCAN(eps, min_samples).fit(X)
except AttributeError:
    arcpy.AddError("Error executing DBSCAN.  DBSCAN only works the first time it is run within an ArcMap session.  Please close and reopen ArcMap and try again.")
    sys.exit()
except arcpy.ExecuteError:
    arcpy.AddError("Error executing DBSCAN in tool")
    sys.exit()
except:
    arcpy.AddError("Non-tool error other than AttributeError executing DBSCAN")
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: What happens when you create your list of lists `X` manually rather than using arcpy?  I ask this because I don't think this is an arcpy/GIS problem, and I think you may need to look more closely at DBSCAN.

Comment: Would you be able to **edit** your question to revise it with this clarification, please?

Comment: Are you able to paste up the full stacktrace of the error?